# Rotation of an object in opengl

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, opengl, visual-studio-2008

I need to rotate the rectangular object upon pressing the left arrow key.

I am not able to rotate it, or maybe it is. There may be a problem playing with the buffer.

Weather the `rotatef()` function is placed correctly or where the problem lies.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<glut.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>


void rot()
{   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();

    glRotatef(30,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
                glVertex2i(50,50);
                glVertex2i(170,50);
                glVertex2i(170,100);
                glVertex2i(50,100);
                glEnd();


    glPopMatrix();
}

void shape()
{

    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);


                glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
                glVertex2i(50,50);
                glVertex2i(170,50);
                glVertex2i(170,100);
                glVertex2i(50,100);
                glEnd();
}
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    shape();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}
void init()
{
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,700,0,700,-1,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}


void Keys(int key,int x,int y)
{
    if(key==GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
        rot();
     glutPostRedisplay();
}

void main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(700,700);
    glutCreateWindow("tetris");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutSpecialFunc(Keys);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Statements like "please, help, urgent" are unnecessary (and maybe counter productive).
Just write a good question(http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and answers will (probably) come

Answer (score 1):

You post a redisplay immediately after drawing your rotated  vertices.
So right after drawing the rotated vertices, in your display callback function, you clear the window and then draw your vertices without rotation. So that is what you'll see (without rotation), until the next update.

One way to proceed is:

1. Do all your drawing in your display function
2. As reaction to a keypress, just update the angle ( I guess you want to rotate incrementally) and post a redisplay. Don't draw anything, your display function will use the updated angle.

Comment: It is getting rotated now incrementally, but not in a particular order  

`glRotatef(angle,0.0,0.0,1.0);`  

angle is initialized with 0 and incremented by 90.  
Still it is being rotated like 90 for 1st time and 270 and 180 and after pressing the left arrow for like >10 times. It goes in order.

Comment: Try  rotating over smaller angles, I think not all rotations are shown. It's like sampling the movement of carwheels in the movies, seemingly rotating backward. Rotate e.g. over 5 degrees, or even 1.

Comment: resolved it sir     `if(key==GLUT_KEY_LEFT)`
`{ angle=90;`  
`if(angle>360)`  
`angle-=360;`  
`}`  

instead of `angle=90; `, I was giving `angle+=90;`